# Retrieve data from xml file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml-parsing

I'm trying to retrieve data from XML file from the URL http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml

The code I'm using is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/j2me/1.0/livematches.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(data){
                        $(data).find('match').each(function(){
                            $(".container").append('<div>'+ 
                              $(this).find("src").text() +'</div>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('error occurred');
                    }   
                    });
               });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But every time I run this code it shows the error part i.e. an alert message "error occurred". Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: Maybe the xml file is not as jQuery expects it to be? Is the doctype set? Did you try method post?

Comment: I tried your code, but getting error `XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{f933cde8-43b9-482f-98c6-8b750a8dfc65} Line Number 1, Column 1:
^` in console

Comment: Yeah @user3154108, I tried both get and post methods but still, it is not working.

Comment: @PankajMakwana question is how can I solve this? I know there is an error but why the error is? Or is this not possible to read XML data from the link given?

Comment: if you can alter the xml file, try add `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the top to make sure the document type is unambigous.

Comment: The XML file is stored at the URL given. I just want to fetch the data from it. I can not alter any part of the file. @user3154108